# How do I make an image work as a link when hovered?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image work as a link but the link doesn't work. I already know what the problem is but I've no clue how to fix it.

If you hover over the image with the cursor the image becomes slightly darker and a few words show up. I want the link to work once I am hovering over the image. If possible I want the link to work over the whole image and not only the text.

If I remove the dark overlay that shows up once you hover, the link works. But, how do I get it to work with the hovering action?

Comment: You need to add more details, code snippets programming language so we can help

Comment: Hi niels and welcome to stack overflow. Please add some code so that we can see what you have tried.

Comment: Can you add few reference pictures so that we can undestand better

Comment: *code is added--

Comment: you didn't add a hyperlink to add a link

Comment: I know and I have tried to add the link in all the div's but none them work because of the hovering action.

Answer (score 1):

I see you didn't add hyperlink, follow below the code.

html,

```
<div class="afbeeldingen_overons_contact">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="afbeelding_links">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/07/11/57/stairway-5551641__340.jpg">
        <div class="info"><h2>Over ons</h2></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I added pixabay for image

if you see the hyperlink clicking event not working you can add your after, before pseudo-element or any overlay tag `pointer-events: none`
then your hyperlink works or if you don't want to use hyperlink tag 'a' you can do it by onclick attribute like `onclick="open('http://')`